# Why isn't PictureBox.Image autoscaling to fit in?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've an interface where user selects picture (using OpenFileDialog) and its shown in a fixed size picturebox. I want this picture to fit in the picturebox even if the resolution is high.

What property do I need to set inorder to let my image AutoScaleToFitIn the PicutreBox?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could set the [PictureBox.SizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx) property to [StretchImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the SizeMode property