# Scaling picturebox size to picture

Tags: c#, winforms

On my Picture box the images shown always appear in a specific height and width shown below:

```
        private void lstpic_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        picbox.ImageLocation = @"C:\Pics\" + (string)lstpic.SelectedItem;
        picbox.Height = 768;
        picbox.Width = 1024;
```

I have set the height and width here, but this only controls the picturebox's height and width, so if I make it smaller each image has part of it cut off. Is there a way I can scale the images instead so they show completely just in a smaller size, rather re sizing the picturebox.

Answer (score 2):

try the `pictureBox1.SizeMode` property

Comment: did you tryed to redraw() / refresh() ?

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742106/why-isnt-picturebox-image-autoscaling-to-fit-in

Answer (score 0):

```
              picbox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

Seemed to work.